# What does the |> operator do in the new ReactiveCocoa 3.0?

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa

So the new swift-based ReactiveCocoa 3.0 has this example on it's main page on github:

```
let searchResults = searchStrings
|> flatMap(.Latest) { query in
    // stuff
}
|> map { data, URLResponse in
    // stuff
}
|> observeOn(UIScheduler())
```

In previous versions of ReactiveCocoa, or in Rx for .NET or other languages, `flatMap`, `map`, `observeOn` are all just extension methods, and you could just as easily do this:

```
let searchResults = searchStrings
  .flatMap(.Latest) { query in
     // stuff
  }
  .map { data, URLResponse in
     // stuff
  }
  .observeOn(UIScheduler())
```

I couldn't find anything in the RAC docs that explained what the difference between those approaches were, and personally I'd much rather have the simple `.` syntax if it can be used in RAC 3.0

Is there anything special that the `|>` operator does? Or are the RAC people just defining operators to feel clever about themselves?

Comment: I've not seen this.  I'm interested too

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `|>` operator is an alias for the `lift` operation, as described in the Signal Producers section of the Reactive Cocoa markdown: [Github docs: Signal Producers](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/FrameworkOverview.md#signal-producers)